# Handling Forcing the Re-loading of an Angular Component When Modal Closes

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

In my Ionic/Angular app I have a situation where I load a modal and then, when the modal closes, I re-load my main component. The problem I was running into is that, based on the way Angular handles component loading, this action wouldn't actually make my main component re-load/re-mount. It would simple show the component in the state as it existed on the stack. This didn't work in my use case, because I need to re-load the component in order for some logic to run to update data that just changed based on what happened in the modal.

I found a way to handle this, but it feels pretty hacky. Basically upon modal close I call a service like so:

```
  async closeModal() {
    await this.modalCtlr.dismiss();
    this.navService.navigateHome();
  }
```

And in my service function I would basically tack on an incremented value so to force the component to re-load, like so:

```
  navigateHome() {
    const incCount = this.counter += 1;
    this.navCtlr.navigateRoot(`/main/${incCount}`);
  }
```

This works, but, as I say, it feels pretty hacky. Is there a built-in Angular way of handling this - to ensure that the component re-loads when an event such as the closing of a modal happens?

Comment: from my experience, if in the "Angular world" you ever find yourself in need to "refresh" the component (or god forbid, the page itself) it's a big red flag saying "reconsider your current state management architecture".

Comment: Maybe, but there are times, as I describe above, where a component won't re-load based on the call stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned this being an Ionic/Angular project. That being the case, Ionic has some additional baked-in functions than can be helpful in exactly these kinds of scenarios.

In your use case the `ionViewWillEnter()` would likely resolve the issue. This goes in your main component file. All you need to do is call the function(s) you need to load within there, like so:

```
runUpdateLogic() {
 // do something necessary here
}

ionViewWillEnter() {
  this.runUpdateLogic();
}
```

Note, to use this implementation you'll also want to use Ionic's `navController` to navigate back to you main component, which I see you're already using. Now it would just look like this:

```
  async closeModal() {
    await this.modalCtlr.dismiss();
    this.navCtlr.navigateRoot(`/main`);
  }
```

This works because, even though in your use case Angular's `ngOnInit()` will not fire in your main component when the modal closes, Ionic's `ionViewWillEnter()` will.

Comment: This worked, and without having to add or change too much of my existing code. Nice.

Answer (score 1):

Move your component initialization code to a separate method, and when you modal closes, call that method again.

For example, if you had something like this:

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.data = somethingFromAService();
  this.someOtherVar = "cool";
}
```

Change to this

```js
initComponent() {
  this.data = somethingFromAService();
  this.someOtherVar = "cool";
}

ngOnInit() {
 this.initComponent();
}

callSomeModal() {
   // assumes the modal has some sort of promise it returns on close, I'm just guessing because there was no example code
   modal.open().then(returnValue => {
      this.initComponent();
   })
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a basic example of what this would look like? Right now routing handles the mounting of components, but in some situations, such as the one I describe, a component won't remount because, as I understand it, it already exists on the stack.

Comment: Can you post your code?  Basicaally, anything you do in ngOnInit or in your constructor or when the router changes, move into a separate method.  You can call that method in the same place, and again when you close your modal.

Comment: But then how would that data be passed back to the component in question? An example with the simplest logic would be helpful.

Comment: How do you get the data in the first place?  You said reinitializing would get the data, so re-run that code.  Or, most modals allow you to return data on close so you could do it that way, or you could have all the data come from a shared service and the modal can update that shared service (using behavior subjects or something similar) so the base component always subscribes to the changes.